# Requery or refresh does not work to update subform on opened form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a search button on a form (form1). The results of the search is displayed in a subform ("SearchResult_sub") on a second form ("frmEquipSearchResults"). The reason I display the result in a subform is that frmEquipSearchResults has buttons to perform action on the search results. So when I open the form the first time everything is fine. But if I leave the result form open , go back to form1 and do another search, the results is not updated on the result form

I tried those 3 lines in the search button to try to requery the result form or the subform it does not work.

```
Forms("frmEquipSearchResults").Form.SearchResult_sub.Requery
Forms("frmEquipSearchResults").SearchResult_sub.Requery
Forms("frmEquipSearchResults").Requery
```

Comment: What is code that applies filter to results form? Is form based on a dynamic parameterized query? What is name of subform container control holding form? "Does not work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: SearchResult_sub is the name of the control that contain the subform. I read in another post that one has to requery the name of the control so that is what I was trying to do. The subform itself is "frmEquipSearchResults"

Comment: Wait, you said SearchResult_sub is ON frmEquipSearchResults so how can it be the subform itself? Did not answer other questions.

Comment: Try: Me.SearchResult_sub.Form.frmEquipSearchResults.Form.Requery
The frmEquipSearchResults should be the sub form container name

Answer (score 0):

Every time I use `Requery` I use a different format.  As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Form.Requery please try:

```
Forms!<MainFormName>!<SubFormName>.Requery
```

or in your case

```
Forms!frmEquipSearchResults!SearchResult_sub.requery
```